# Getting error while accessing webservices through apache axis2

Tags: java, apache, web-services, jsp, apache-axis

The following is the error, can anybody help me in fixing this error. Is this any package missing error?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 47 in the jsp file: /axis2-web/include/httpbase.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
44: public String calculateHttpBase(HttpServletRequest aRequest) {
45: StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
46: if (frontendHostUrl != null) {
47: stringBuffer.append(frontendHostUrl);
48: } else {
49: String scheme = aRequest.getScheme();
50: stringBuffer.append(scheme);
```

Any help?